# Cannot uninstall docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I am trying to uninstall docker

The command I am using is:

```
sudo apt-get purge -y docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce docker-ce-cli
```

The error I get:

```
E: Type '<!DOCTYPE' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Type '<!DOCTYPE' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I have uninstalled docker before but never ran into this. Does anyone know what this means?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list` is corrupt.
Try manually deleting it, and then running the `apt` command again.

You're removing docker, so definitely won't need this entry any more